# Facebook plugin ie8 and ie7 SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by https://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, facebook-comments

Does anyone get this error :

SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by https://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php

In IE8 and IE7 when implimenting Facebook comments plugin:

```
<html lang="en"  xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
...
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

    //helps fix ie securrity errors
    FB._https = true;

    FB.init({
      appId      : '408511102504009', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//mv.uat.venda.com/page/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>


<fb:comments href="http://mv.uat.venda.com/denim/test-outfit/invt/7999999999996/" num_posts="3" width="395"></fb:comments>
```